# Windows 10: Icons in taskbar have wrong size

Tags: windows, icons, windows-10, taskbar

Since Windows 10 the Icons in the taskbar seems to have a size of 24x24px.
This would be no problem, if Windows would choose the 24px version in an icon file for display. But it choose the 32px version and scales it down. That results in ugly artifacts, especially if you have striaght lines in your icons.
Is this a core windows problem or are there any known workarounds?
Tested with a plain WinForms (C#) application and a Delphi Application.

Comment: I use StartIsBack++ to get the larger 32pixel Icons back: http://startisback.com/

Comment: This is not an option ... since this is a problem of all our customers with our software seeing blurry icons of our application in the win 10 taskbar.

Comment: send feedback to MS so that they fix the issue or officially support 32Px icons again

Comment: are you sure that this is what happens? how?